# C# page navi PHP scrape

Tags: c#, php, web-scraping

i tried to scrape this page:
http://eshop.saphokft.hu/shop/Productslist.aspx?CategoryCode=sprchove-zasteny

i tried to load 9. page from navi with PHP cURL, but i is not working.

i can just 1-8 scrape, but i cannot step from 8 to 9. page.

what is the problem? I tried to with phantomJs and simple PHP cURL.

```
function downloadUrl($url){
    //$content = 'error';
    $client = Client::getInstance();
    //$p = explode(':', $proxy);
    //$Proxy = $p[0];
    //$proxyPort = $p[0];
    //$client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy=176.61.143.43:80");
    //$client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy-auth=".$proxyUser.":".$proxyPassword."");
    $client->getEngine()->setPath('/home/admin/web/xyz/public_html/bin/phantomjs');
    //$client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy=".$proxy."");
    //$client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy-auth=".$proxyUser.":".$proxyPassword."");
    $client->getEngine()->addOption("--proxy-type=http");

    $file = '/home/admin/web/xyz/public_html/stemp/pcookies.txt';
    $client->getEngine()->addOption('--cookies-file='.$file);

    $request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

    //$request->setMethod('GET');
    $data = array(
        'ctl00$ScriptManager1' => 'ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel2|ctl00$MainContent$pagerTop$ctl01$ctl02',
        //'ctl00$HiddenSearchCategory' => '#all',
        //'ctl00$searchtext' => '',
        //'ctl00$MainContent$HiddenFilter' => '[{"filterValue":"sprchove-zasteny","filterType":"pcategoria"},{"filterValue":"ctvrtkruhove-zasteny","filterType":"categoria"}]',
        //'ctl00$MainContent$ex2' => '7990,686990',
        //'min' => '7990',
        //'max' => '686990',
        'ctl00$MainContent$HiddenField1' => 'PageChanged',
        '__EVENTTARGET' => 'ctl00$MainContent$pagerTop$ctl01$ctl02',
        '__VIEWSTATE' => '',
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => '5956E682',
        '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED' => '5956E682',
        '__ASYNCPOST' => 'true',
    );
    $request->setMethod('POST');
    $request->setUrl($url);
    $request->setRequestData($data);

    $client->send($request, $response);

    if($response->getStatus() === 200) {
        $content = $response->getContent();
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: yes, sorry. Where can i edit this post? :)

Comment: Can you help me in my Problem too? :D

Comment: the number 9 page has the same ID, AS 3: ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel2|ctl00$MainContent$pagerTop$ctl01$ctl02

Comment: because the site made with c#. do you scrape number 9 page? it is the problem..